# Edge-based HTML Renderer for Outlook Add-in: window.open() popup is missing maximize button

Tags: javascript, outlook, office365, outlook-web-addins

Add-ins on the Outlook for Windows 10 desktop app use **Edge-based HTML renderer**. I'm trying to open a popup with window.open() command shown below:

```js
var popupDimensions = "height=800,width=600";
var link = 'https://same-domain-of-addin.com/some/page';
window.open(link, null, [
            popupDimensions,
            "resizable",
            "scrollbars",
            "location",
            "status",
            "menubar"
        ].join(','));
```

This opens **a new popup dialog (which is again Edge-based )** but however it does not honor these flags fully:

- "resizable"       -> While I can drag around the edges to enlarge it,
  the **maximize button is not there**
- "popupDimensions" -> **Height and width are not honored**. By
  default, it's opening at roughly 50% height and width of my screen (assume my desktop's res is 1280x720)

Is there a workaround to make the window have the following properties? (**in descending order of preference**):

1. show maximize button
2. show the window maximized (second best case)
3. use default browser (best case for us)
4. set the window size when opening (minimum improvement required)

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is by-design. The windowFeatures parameters are not applicable in Edge Webview based win-32 Outlook.  We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.

An alternative is to call window.open with a url that is not in a domain in your AppDomains. This will pop out to the default browser instead.